# Do Messianic Jews practice the jubliee?

Tags: mosaic-law, jubilee, messianic-judaism

There is a a range of opinion of different denominations on how far Mosaic law should be practiced. [Messianic Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messianic_Judaism) stands very much at the "one law" end of the scale. However, I am wondering how far this is practicable. Some Mosaic law is difficult to practice within a larger context. For example, Messianic Jews do not generally (as far as I know never) stone people. However, I was wondering if they practice the [jubilee year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_%28biblical%29)? Although this would be difficult for them concerning outside trading it could be practicable within the group.

Comment: To note, the commandment applies to those who live in the land of Israel (Lev. 25:2), not in the diaspora.

Comment: Yes, however, even if only practiced within Israel, quite a large portion of Messianic Jews live there.

Answer (score 1):

The messianic community is very diverse and complex, like the various christian denominations.
There is no official body or teaching on how far to apply the mosaic law.
Most of the messianic believers are not that strict orthodox as one might expect (at least not in Israel), to most of them the year of jubilee and the shmitah (every 7th year) does not really apply. However there are some more religious messianics who keep it and for example to not buy fruits and vegetables in the shmitah year from Israel.
This is due to the fact that the laws for the jubilee and the shmitah mostly apply to agricultue, selling and redeeming property (mostly land) and freeing slaves.
Most of these things, except the first one do not apply to the modern society anymore.
However what applies they are trying to keep, due to the understanding that the laws are also give with a reason.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! And thanks for providing the first answer for this question. Can you provide any references to documents by scholars or particular Messianic Jewish groups that offer further information on the subject? If so, that would give your answer some extra oomph for this site. For some good tips on giving answers here, please see [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)